# Download future price series from Yahoo! with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo, finance

That's strange, I have been unable to download future price series from Yahoo! with panda.

Take this snippet which is supposed to download prices for CBoT corn Sept-13 :

```
import pandas.io.data as fetch
ts = fetch.get_data_yahoo('CU13.CBT', '8/8/2013', '10/8/2013')
print(ts)
```

I get a weblink error message:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I have tried other underlying (metals, livestock ...), and different maturities but that just doesn't work. I have also tried tricks such as removing the .CBT part but with no success

Comment: Run fiddler and see what request you're sending to yahoo. Post it here, and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Maybe the server is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a pandas problem, historical data for **CU13.CBT** is not available, you can check that [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CU13.CBT&ql=1) you wont find the link to historical prices (compare with [this](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=F&ql=1)).

[image: Yahoo historical prices]

Try with another symbol and it should work. Example:

```
>>> import pandas.io.data as web

>>> start = datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 8)
>>> end = datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 10)
>>> f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
>>> f
             Open    High    Low     Close   Volume      Adj Close
Date                        
2013-08-08   16.94   17.03   16.87   16.98   26589500    16.98
2013-08-09   16.95   17.11   16.94   17.02   25625300    17.02
```

Comment: Do you think it's worth filing a bug on Pandas? They might want to handle the 404 more gracefully.

Comment: not sure about it, this is the error I get "IOError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=CU13.CBT&a=7&b=8&c=2013&d=7&e=10&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv'"

Comment: Looking at the code, that is what I would expect as well. I wonder what version of Pandas OP is using.

Comment: @audiodude yes! please do :)